# JPA/Spring-boot Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using JPA for mysql operations, but the few times I am getting error while performing mysql save operations through JPA.
Error while performing save operation =>

> Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY'

**Table Model Class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="table_x")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Data
@TypeDefs({
        @TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonStringType.class),
        @TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class),
})
public class tableX implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="product_id")
    private Long productId;

    @Column(name="parent_id")
    private Long parentId;

    // other fields
}
```

**Mysql Schema:**

```
 CREATE TABLE `table_x` (
  `product_id` int(12) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(12) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  // other fields
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`)
)
```

**Repository Class:**

```
@Repository
public interface TableXRepository extends CrudRepository<tableX,Long> {
}
```

**Mysql Operation Class:**

```
@Component
@Transactional
public class tableXoperationImpl implements ItableXoperation {

    @Autowired
    private TableXRepository tableXRepository;

    public void save(tableX data) {
        tableXRepository.save(data);
    }
}
```

is anything, I am missing here, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add more  of your log file, and is there source code for the test or client code which is calling the ITableXoperation interface. As a point the class names should be be lower case in java.

Comment: What are the data you used to perform save operation. You would have used duplicate `product_id`

Comment: @IsharaMadhawa i think, if you save document with same product_id, jpa will update in place of insert if document already exist..

Answer (score 2):

Please use the `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` on `productId`.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem with your column `product_id` which actually defined as primary key in table.

```
@Id  //this annotation make column as primary key.
@Column(name="product_id")
private Long productId;
```

You can assign `productId` either by yourself or assign a **Id Generation Strategy**  [Primary Key Id Generation Strategy Type](https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/generated).

if you decide to assign productId by yourself then it must be unique (not exists in that column in that table (product)).

If you look your exception closely you will find this out  `Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY'` , Which means try to insert duplicate value in primary key column (product_id) of table (Product).

or you may replace above primary key column code with this

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) // automatically generated primary key.
@Id  // Primary key.
@Column(name="product_id")
private Long productId;
```

Thanks :)

Comment: as far as I know, if you save document again through jpa, it will update the document if it already exist.

Comment: @AmitKumar yes it is right.. but you should assign a generationType for primary key column may solve your problem..

Comment: @AmitKumar Please refer this atleast once https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-crud-repository-save

Comment: Vikrant Kashyap, hi I cannot put auto generation type because I am consuming data from kafka pipeline and saving into mysql, so all parameters are coming from there, and thanks for the link, I already go through the given link, I just wondering why jpa save throwing error it should update in case of duplicate document, 
And I also performed the save operation test cases with same document multiple times but i did not get error

Answer (score 0):

In my case I inserted data from a CSV and `hibernate_sequence` got out of sync which caused problems with `save`/`saveAll`.

Just edit the `hibernate_sequence` to the latest id+1 and it should work